# Why does this line of PHP not pass the data correctly to the function?

Tags: php

My apologies I can not give the source for the $db class.
Why does this line of PHP in between the () give e an error?

```
$q = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM realsteal WHERE email = " . $db->decrypt($email) " OR cell = " . $db->decrypt($cell) ");
```

Comment: I suggest you to get a good IDE (like [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [Eclips](http://www.eclipse.org/)) displaying errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a concatenation operator after `$email)` and an errant `"`

**However, please stop writing queries via string substitution and move to prepared statements ASAP.**

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `"` in the end. And a missing concatenation operator.

```
"SELECT * FROM realsteal WHERE email = " . $db->decrypt($email) . " OR cell = " . $db->decrypt($cell)
```

Also, I don't know what your `decrypt` method does, but if `$email` and/or `$cell` are strings, you should mark them as a string in the SQL statement (put `'` around them).

**Honestly, you should look into using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements. It would clean up this mess.**

Answer (score 0):

You are missing concatenation operator and have extra quote in the end of the query. The correct code would be:

```
$q = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM realsteal WHERE email = " . $db->decrypt($email) . " OR cell = " . $db->decrypt($cell));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors. Here 's the correct line:

`$q = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM realsteal WHERE email = " . $db->decrypt($email) . " OR cell = " . $db->decrypt($cell));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM realsteal WHERE email = " . $db->decrypt($email) " OR cell = " . $db->decrypt($cell) ");
```

misses a concatenator after `$db->decrypt($email)`

and there is an extra `"` before `);`

```
$q = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM realsteal WHERE email = " . $db->decrypt($email) . " OR cell = " . $db->decrypt($cell) );
```